# OpenGL fragment shader has too many instructions

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm writing a Level Editor in C# and OpenTK, and wanted to see if a more complex shader would work fine. So I grabbed this mine craft shader here https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MdlGz4.

But I can't get it to work, I keep getting this error:

```
Failed to link shader program!
Fragment info
-------------
Internal error: assembly compile error for fragment shader at offset 392911:
-- error message --
line 16405, column 1:  error: too many instructions
-- internal assembly text --
!!NVfp5.0
OPTION NV_bindless_texture;
OPTION NV_shader_atomic_float;
# cgc version 3.1.0001, build date Feb  9 2013
# command line args: 
#vendor NVIDIA Corporation
#version 3.1.0.1
#profile gp5fp
```

The shadertoy version runs fine in my browser. So I know my hardware (GTX 680) can handle it. I'm using #version 400 in the fragment shader, in the hope that a higher version allows for more instructions. But that did not help either.
So my question is, how do I have to load/compile such a long fragment shader?

Here's the actual shader that I'm trying to run:

**Vertex:**

```
#version 400

uniform mat4 camera;
uniform mat4 model;
in vec3 in_vertex;
in vec4 in_color;
in vec2 in_uv;
out vec2 frag_TexCoord;
out vec4 frag_Color;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = camera * model * vec4(in_vertex, 1);
    frag_TexCoord = in_uv;
    frag_Color = in_color;
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
#version 400

uniform vec2 iResolution;
uniform float iGlobalTime;
in vec4 frag_Color;
in vec2 frag_TexCoord;
out vec4 final_color;

// Created by Reinder Nijhoff 2013
//
// port of javascript minecraft: http://jsfiddle.net/uzMPU/
// original code by Markus Persson: https://twitter.com/notch/status/275331530040160256

float hash( float n ) {
    return fract(sin(n)*43758.5453);
}

// port of minecraft

bool getMaterialColor( int i, vec2 coord, out vec3 color ) {
    // 16x16 tex
    vec2 uv = floor( coord );

    float n = uv.x + uv.y*347.0 + 4321.0 * float(i);
    float h = hash(n);

    float br = 1. - h * (96./255.
                        );
    color = vec3( 150./255., 108./255.,  74./255.); // 0x966C4A;

    if (i == 4) {
        color = vec3( 127./255., 127./255., 127./255.); // 0x7F7F7F;
    }

    float xm1 = mod((uv.x * uv.x * 3. + uv.x * 81.) / 4., 4.);

    if (i == 1) {
        if( uv.y < (xm1 + 18.)) {
            color = vec3( 106./255., 170./255.,  64./255.); // 0x6AAA40;
        } else if (uv.y < (xm1 + 19.)) {
            br = br * (2. / 3.);
        }
    }

    if (i == 7) {
        color = vec3( 103./255., 82./255.,  49./255.); // 0x675231;
        if (uv.x > 0. && uv.x < 15.
            && ((uv.y > 0. && uv.y < 15.) || (uv.y > 32. && uv.y < 47.))) {
            color = vec3( 188./255., 152./255.,  98./255.); // 0xBC9862;
            float xd = (uv.x - 7.);
            float yd = (mod(uv.y, 16.) - 7.);
            if (xd < 0.)
                xd = 1. - xd;
            if (yd < 0.)
                yd = 1. - yd;
            if (yd > xd)
                xd = yd;

            br = 1. - (h * (32./255.) + mod(xd, 4.) * (32./255.));
        } else if ( h < 0.5 ) {
            br = br * (1.5 - mod(uv.x, 2.));
        }
    }

    if (i == 5) {
        color = vec3( 181./255.,  58./255.,  21./255.); // 0xB53A15;
        if ( mod(uv.x + (floor(uv.y / 4.) * 5.), 8.) == 0. || mod( uv.y, 4.) == 0.) {
            color = vec3( 188./255., 175./255., 165./255.); // 0xBCAFA5;
        }
    }
    if (i == 9) {
        color = vec3(  64./255.,  64./255., 255./255.); // 0x4040ff;
    }

    float brr = br;
    if (uv.y >= 32.)
        brr /= 2.;

    if (i == 8) {
        color = vec3(  80./255., 217./255.,  55./255.); // 0x50D937;
        if ( h < 0.5) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    color *= brr;

    return true;
}

int getMap( vec3 pos ) {    
    vec3 posf = floor( (pos - vec3(32.))  );

    float n = posf.x + posf.y*517.0 + 1313.0*posf.z;
    float h = hash(n);

    if( h > sqrt( sqrt( dot( posf.yz, posf.yz )*0.16 ) ) - 0.8  ) {
        return 0;
    }   

    return int( hash( n * 465.233 ) * 16. );
}

vec3 renderMinecraft( vec2 uv ) {
    float xRot = sin( iGlobalTime*0.5 ) * 0.4 + (3.1415 / 2.);
    float yRot = cos( iGlobalTime*0.5 ) * 0.4;
    float yCos = cos(yRot);
    float ySin = sin(yRot);
    float xCos = cos(xRot);
    float xSin = sin(xRot);

    vec3 opos = vec3( 32.5 + iGlobalTime * 6.4, 32.5, 32.5 );

    float gggxd = (uv.x - 0.5) * (iResolution.x / iResolution.y );
    float ggyd = (1.-uv.y - 0.5);
    float ggzd = 1.;

    float gggzd = ggzd * yCos + ggyd * ySin;

    vec3 _posd = vec3( gggxd * xCos + gggzd * xSin,
                       ggyd * yCos - ggzd * ySin,
                       gggzd * xCos - gggxd * xSin );

    vec3 col = vec3( 0. );
    float br = 1.;
    vec3 bdist = vec3( 255. - 100., 255. -   0., 255. -  50.  );
    float ddist = 0.;

    float closest = 32.;

    for ( int d = 0; d < 3; d++) {
        float dimLength = _posd[d];

        float ll = abs( 1. / dimLength );
        vec3 posd = _posd * ll;;

        float initial = fract( opos[d] );
        if (dimLength > 0.) initial = 1. - initial;

        float dist = ll * initial;

        vec3 pos = opos + posd * initial;

        if (dimLength < 0.) {
            pos[d] -= 1.;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {
            if( dist > closest )continue;

            //int tex = getMap( mod( pos, 64. ) );
            int tex = getMap( pos );

            if (tex > 0) {
                vec2 texcoord;
                texcoord.x = mod(((pos.x + pos.z) * 16.), 16.);
                texcoord.y = mod((pos.y * 16.), 16.) + 16.;
                if (d == 1) {
                    texcoord.x = mod(pos.x * 16., 16.);
                    texcoord.y = mod(pos.z * 16., 16.);
                    if (posd.y < 0.)
                        texcoord.y += 32.;
                }

                if ( getMaterialColor( tex, texcoord, col ) ) {
                    ddist = 1. - (dist / 32.);
                    br = bdist[d];
                    closest = dist;
                }
            }
            pos += posd;
            dist += ll;
        }
    }

    return col * ddist * (br/255.);
}

void main()
{
    vec2 uv = frag_TexCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    final_color = vec4( renderMinecraft( uv ) ,1.0);
}
```

**Clarification as to where the error happens:**
The frist two steps of compiling the vertex and fragment shader work fine. It's the linking (GL.GetProgram()) that returns 0. The call to GL.GetProgramInfo returns the above mentioned error and lists the program in assembly code (# 19337 instructions, 8 R-regs). So it does have so many lines.

```
_vertexShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
GL.ShaderSource(_vertexShader, vertexProgram);
GL.CompileShader(_vertexShader);
GL.GetShader(_vertexShader, ShaderParameter.CompileStatus, out result);
if (result == 0)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(GL.GetString(StringName.ShadingLanguageVersion));
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(GL.GetShaderInfoLog(_vertexShader));
}

//Create Fragment Shader
_fragShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);
GL.ShaderSource(_fragShader, fragmentProgram);
GL.CompileShader(_fragShader);
GL.GetShader(_fragShader, ShaderParameter.CompileStatus, out result);
if (result == 0)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(GL.GetString(StringName.ShadingLanguageVersion));
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(GL.GetShaderInfoLog(_fragShader));
}

//Link to program
_shader = GL.CreateProgram();
GL.AttachShader(_shader, _vertexShader);
GL.AttachShader(_shader, _fragShader);
GL.LinkProgram(_shader);
GL.GetProgram(_shader, ProgramParameter.LinkStatus, out result);
if (result == 0)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Failed to link shader program!");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(GL.GetProgramInfoLog(_shader));
    GL.DeleteProgram(_shader);
}
```

Comment: Could you put the *actual* shader you trying to compile in your question?

Comment: Sorry, should have included that.

Comment: Double-check the string you are passing as a fragment shader.  You must be passing something else...maybe uninitialized data?  The text you include does not have sixteen thousand lines.

line 16405, column 1:  error: too many instructions

Comment: Try adding newline at the end.

Comment: I added some more details as to where the problem is happening. It must fail during glLinkProgram() since glGetProgram(LinkStatus) return false. And glGetProgramInfoLog() returns me assemlby code that is over 19,000 lines long. So I must assume that the compiling of the program went fine, it's just too long?

Comment: Is your shader string null terminated? It sounds like the compiler's running off the end of the string!

Comment: I'm using C# so string handling is not the issue. Also the glCompileShader() calls run without error. It's during the linking glLinkProgram() that the problem occurs. Appreciate the help though!